# Secure access redirection

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to use nginx to serve files from

https://example.com/documents/*

But to redirect all other requests to `localhost:4443`. I need to use `stream` to pass on the **client certificate** to the listening application on `4443`, since otherwise it seems that nginx conducts the TLS handshake and it fails.

I have tried this, but nginx claims (of course) that the 443 port is in use:

```
http {
    server {
            listen 443;
            location /documents/ {
                    sendfile        on;
            }
}
stream {
        server {
                listen  443;
                proxy_pass      localhost:4443;
        }
}
```

I cannot use another port, it should be the same port.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Do you really mean redirect, or route aka proxy? To make a routing decision based on the URL, nginx has to terminate (i.e. decrypt) the SSL/TLS connection, but as you correctly say, if it terminates SSL/TLS it cannot pass on any client cert. You could have nginx return a _redirect_ to 4443 using `return 30x {url}` or `rewrite {absurl} | {url} redirect|permanent` , but with a name valid for the client not `localhost`, and then the _client_ will connect to 4443 _with_ the client cert and re-send the request there.

Comment: See if this helps https://serverfault.com/questions/835984/nginx-reverse-proxy-passthrough-of-client-tls-certificate

Comment: I will try your suggestion @dave_thompson_085. (The "redirect" I mean is as you can see in the configuration, just a way to "pass it on" to another application whatever it was received)

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it is not possible to do what I need.... Either an additional server name or an additional server port is needed to distinguish the destination of the request